Python use win32com connect windows to change windows password
I successfully connected to windows remotely using the win32com module. But I don't know how to change the account password through the connection.
I tried to create a process using Win32_Process's Create method and execute the "net user" command, but it didn't work.  The returned error is:'int' object is not callable
    locator = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    wmi_service = locator.ConnectServer(remote_computer, "root\\cimv2", username, password)
    process = wmi_service.Get("Win32_Process")
    cmd= f'net user "{username}" "{new_password}"'

    # 在远程计算机上执行命令，Create返回两个值：result和进程ID
    result, = process.Create(command=cmd)
    
    if result == 0:
        print(f"Password for {username} changed successfully on {remote_computer}.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to change password for {username}. Error code: {result}")



Did you update win32com? Released: Oct 4, 2024

Welcome to SO! Why is this question tagged "bash"?
